# Angular Schema Form vs Roll Your Own

Tags: angular-schema-form

I am trying to use **angular schema form**, http://schemaform.io/ While I find it great, I think it is too much like a platform solution and I am having to dig into the code to truly understand it in order to get it doing what I need with custom decorators. I am also finding the 'shema=' vs 'form=' to be very confusing.

I am now leaning towards the 'roll your own', Can anyone recommend using another package other than angular-schema-form or going the home grown route to maintain control?  I have a hard time relying on 3rd party products when I don't fully understand them (or would code them differently) or if they will suite our needs.

So any options out there besides schema-form or any good starter packages for a home grown form generator using angularjs?

Comment: I looked at this, not at the code level, but wound up going with schema form. I would like to know if anyone has actual experience with using another form solution or if they just went with their own because the packages didn't cut it.  The biggest issue, is **when there is an issue** and you basically have to learn the code to figure it out.  At that point, it seems like rolling your own may work better.  Looking for some guidance on experiences...thanks for the link though!

Comment: I'll tell you what, angularjs-form-builder does seem to have a more logical json schema, http://selmanh.github.io/angularjs-form-builder/#/forms/1/view Thanks for re-introducing me to it.

Comment: Rolling your own isn't always better because you will end up re-inventing the wheel and spending a lot of time getting small details right. Consider learning Angular Schema Form and adapting it as if it was yours. Then, contribute your changes and improvements back to the community. This is the way of open source. Together we can do something much greater than any of us alone.

Answer (score 2):

Angular Schema Form at its core is a template manager to reduce effort and manage re-use easily via config. You are more than capable to make your own Angular components and pass information to them via the UI Schema.

To elaborate on the differences JSON Schema is a standard for defining data models and the UI Schema (form) definition in ASF is specifically for the presentation layer, this also includes overrides of some data model properties.

There is no point in rolling a custom solution when knowing the internal workings of an open source offering provides you the ability to contribute and improve the library which is an even better result that everyone doing their own thing and re-inventing the wheel each time.